# Prove that $G = \{a+b\sqrt{2}\}$ is an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $G = \{a+b\sqrt2 \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$, prove that $(G,+)$ is an abelian group.

I know that I just have to show the definition of an abelian group holds for this set but I'm wondering now what I'm even allowed to use to prove that? I mean, we could just argue that all numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt2$ are real numbers and for example commutativity would directly follow, but I saw a proof in a book using the fact that

$$(a+b\sqrt2) + (c+d\sqrt2) = (a + c) + (b + d)\sqrt2.$$

But at that stage in the book, the distributive law hasn't been introduced yet, so why are we allowed to use that?

Comment: It could be that addition was simply defined in that way in the group

Comment: Yes, I was assuming it was the ordinary addition, because nothing else is mentioned

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that the book assumes all of the properties of addition and multiplication on $\mathbb R$ and goes from there. Note that this is reasonable since construction of real numbers is non-trivial matter and you probably won't find it in your textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* If addition in $G$ is defined by $(a+b\sqrt2) + (c+d\sqrt2) = (a + c) + (b + d)\sqrt2$, then it coincides with the addition in $\mathbb R \supseteq G$, and there is not much left to prove.

Comment: One needs to prove closure under operations so that $G$ is indeed a subgroup.

Comment: @Ennar, indeed. I didn't say there was *nothing* left to prove...

Comment: Ok, you are right. I interpreted it that way and just wanted to clarify for OP who seems unsure of what is required of them.